# Paypal IPN - decimal delimiter change

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I use CiviCRM 4.7.23, Drupal 7.56

I try set a payment processor: PayPal. I use my CiviCRM in Poland, where decimal delimiter is ",". After test transaction on paypal i see this in logs:

> $Fatal Error Details = array(3) { ["message"]=> string(40) "fee_amount is not a valid amount: 29.80" ["code"]=> NULL ["exception"]=> object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#181 (8) { ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=> array(3) { ["is_error"]=> int(1) ["error_message"]=> string(40) "fee_amount is not a valid amount: 29.80" ["error_code"]=> string(9) "undefined" } ["message":protected]=> string(40) "fee_amount is not a valid amount: 29.80" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(93) "/home/sol/domains/staroflife.hekko24.pl/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php" ["line":protected]=> int(45) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(13) { [0]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(117) "/home/sol/domains/staroflife.hekko24.pl/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php" ["line"]=> int(4693) ["function"]=> string(12) "civicrm_api3" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(12) "Contribution" [1]=> string(6) "create" [2]=> array(11) { ["contribution_status_id"]=> int(1) ["source"]=> string(40) "Transakcja online: Pomóż nam pomagać!" ["is_test"]=> int(1) ["fee_amount"]=> string(5) "29.80" ["net_amount"]=> NULL ["trxn_id"]=> string(17) "7F503721X74500702" ["payment_processor"]=> string(1) "8" ["payment_instrument_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["receive_date"]=> string(14) "20170903013615" ["id"]=> string(2) "86" ["version"]=> int(3) } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(110)
>
> and more, more text here https://staroflife-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lewandowski_marcin_staroflife_pl/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0025a0d10dbea4f9d9145381c2595ddeb&authkey=AYd_FW8zlLwY2fA5i0Lebd8

How i can change decimal delimiter only for PayPal. Ideally, something would convert a dot to a comma after receiving a return message.

Comment: Can you post the more, more text - even if you post in a pastebin & link to it - the important part is in the more test

Comment: All errors i insert in this file. https://staroflife-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lewandowski_marcin_staroflife_pl/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0025a0d10dbea4f9d9145381c2595ddeb&authkey=AYd_FW8zlLwY2fA5i0Lebd8